# If the AraC protein was a gene repressor when it binds arabinose, would there be high or low transcription levels when arabinose is present?

Tags: gene, transcription, plasmids, gene-regulation, operons

If the AraC protein were to function as a gene repressor when it binds arabinose, would there be high or low transcription levels when arabinose is present?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, your question isn't clear and shows no evidence of prior research. Unclear because you haven't specified what gene(s) you are interested in. Under researched because you haven't said where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please note that both of these are considered to be reasons for down-voting and closure on this site.

Answer (score 2):

A repressor inhibits transcription, thus one expects low transcription when the repressor is present.

Thus, if a protein acts as a repressor when it binds arabinose, then when arabinose is present the protein will inhibit transcription.

In the typical synthetic case of AraC and pBAD, AraC+arabinose does *not* act like a repressor, but an activator of pBAD.  There are some awfully big caveats there, however:

- If "high" and "low" transcription levels are not well-defined, you might find yourself be dealing with a different phenomenon entirely.
- If you change the promoter or the genetic or environmental context, you may get different effects, up to and including changing the regulatory relationship.
- Transcription is also affected by other things, and so if AraC is also affecting other things in the cell, the apparent affect might be inverted as well.

Bottom line: you need to actually define the system better in order to predict the effects.